# Basic Python function in azure notebook

Tags: python, azure

Morning folks, so I've been learning python recently to get into programming and whatnot, and I've hit a bump when learning functions.

I'm using the azure notebook IDE and when I try to run this code:

```
say_cheese():
print("Say cheese, kids!")
print("Cheese!")

say_cheese()
```

It's not working and I don't understand why. There's no syntax error, it just doesn't get an output.

Comment: Syntax is `def funcname():` and you have to indent what you want to be inside the function. So indent the print lines and add `def` at the beginning of the 1st line

Comment: Hi,any updates now?

Comment: yes, It works just fine now, thanks a bunch![sorry that I didn't let you know though..internet was being a hassle as of lately]

Comment: @T.Amit Never mind. You could mark the below answer for others' reference on the forum.Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You missed the keyword in the Python method definition: **def**.

Your code need to be like this:

```
def say_cheese():
  print("Say cheese, kids!")
  print("Cheese!")

say_cheese()
```

Please pay attention to the points:

1.Define the method before you call it

2.Indentation is sensitive in Python code ,thus method body needs to be indented.

Please refer to this [article](https://www.learnpython.org/en/Functions) for more details.

Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

well, in Python you need to use `def functionname():` to define a function, you also need to indent code inside function